# Tying ComboBox/NumericUpDown selections to an array?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, combobox

I'm working on a VB project that has a lot of comboboxes and numericupdown items.

Lets say we have ComboBox1, 2, 3, 4, and 5; and we have NumericUpDown1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

When the user clicks the "Save" button, I want to save all of their selected combobox items and numericupdown numbers to a CSV file.  Is there an elegant/automatic way to tie all of the .SelectedIndex and .Value for these items to an array so I can easily write the array out to a CSV?

The only way I know to do this so far is to manually associate each one with an array position:

```
Arr(0) = ComboBox1.SelectedIndex
Arr(1) = ComboBox2.SelectedIndex
...
Arr(5) = NumericUpDown1.Value
Arr(6) = NumericUpDown2.Value
...
etc.
```

This wouldnt be too bad, except I have a LOT of these items, and writing a line for each one seems silly.  I'm new to VB, so this might be an obvious solution to some.  Any ideas?

Having them bound to an array would be really handy because I also allow the user to Load a CSV file, which I would like to automatically populate the ComboBoxes and NumericUpDowns from the CSV values.   The only way I know to do this is to manually move each array item to the respective combobox/numeric item when they click the Load file button:

```
ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = Arr(0)
ComboBox2.SelectedIndex = Arr(1)
...
NumericUpDown1.Value = Arr(5)
NumericUpDown2.Value = Arr(6)
...
etc.
```

Edit: Here is some application info as requested...

The CSV file that can be saved/loaded looks like this:

```
#"Device Info","123456","asdfgh","0000","1.0x","1"
000F,0000,0032,0000,00C8,0001,0078,0101,0000,0001,0000,0001
010F,0078,0000,0103,0001,0000,000A,0005,0007,0006,0000
0001,000A,000A,000A,000A,0005,0005,0005,0002
...etc
```

The header line just has serial number, version, and other misc info; it is automatically generated by the target device.  All of the other lines are configuration setpoints that the target device reads in and automatically configures itself.  I'm writing this PC program to be able to edit (and create from scratch) these configuration CSV files with a nice GUI interface.  Each item is tied to a specific setpoint, such as 000F = Language, 0032 = System Frequency, 00C8 = System Voltage, etc.  The easiest way I saw to make this configuration program was to use numeric entry and drop-down comboboxes that the user can select what they want.  Each NUD and CBOX equates to one of the CSV file data fields.

Comment: The array is just an intermediary.  there is no reason (stated) the data could not go directly from the controls to file and vice versa.

Comment: @Plutonx With an array, I could iterate through the array easily to output to a CSV, right?  But with a bunch of ComboBox.SelectedIndexes, how would you index through to output to the CSV?

Comment: `streamwriter.WriteList("{0}, {1}", cbo1.SelectedIndex.ToString, nud1.Value.ToString)` so, yes you dont have an index to use it in a loop, but you arent going to have one putting the values *into* the array either - its just an extra step.  Also, saving the Index means the cbo will always and forever have the same contents.  Bad assumption.  Better to save the text value.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not familiar with WriteList.  Any tutorials or examples on that?  I could see how that might be a problem.  My combobox items are hard-defined and should never change (other than adding a new item on to the end of the item list in the future), so I think it'll be okay in my case.  Good suggestion in case the items are editable by the user.

Comment: sorry, should be `WriteLine`

Comment: Ah, alright.  One reason tying these items to an array would help me is that the CSV data is easily dumped into an array upon a file Load.  I then have to manually move each array value into its respective combobox/numericupdown item.  It's tedious, and I figured there had to be a better way.

Comment: since each CBO and NUD seem logically linked, a class to keep them together, then a collection or list of them for all of them makes sense.  Loading and updating gets simpler because it is abstracted. *Arrays* introduce tedium.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Controls.Find() to get a reference to the desired control based on an index value.  Here's a quick example to demonstrate what I mean:

```
For i As Integer = 1 To 30
    Dim matches() As Control = Me.Controls.Find("NumericUpDown" & i, True)
    If matches.Length > 0 AndAlso TypeOf matches(0) Is NumericUpDown Then
        DirectCast(matches(0), NumericUpDown).Value = i
    End If
Next
```

You can incorporate code like that into the load/save routines.

Comment: That's pretty interesting. It's beyond my current VB understanding, but I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

I would use binary serialization. This eliminates the need to format strings or xml when saving control properties. Similar to Plutonix's solution, it only works on certain types of control. However, it can be modified to work on any type of control - but only supports a single property to be loaded for each control. It will work on all controls of *type* `X` instead of controls *named* `xName`. You can add further restrictions by grouping the controls to be serialized in a panel or other means.

Make a new Form called Form1. Add some NumericUpDowns, TextBoxes, and ComboBoxes. Put some values in the ComboBoxes at design time, otherwise calling `loadState()` in `Form_Load` will be meaningless. However, `loadState()` can be called whenever (i.e. after the comboboxes have been populated).

You will need to import these two namespaces:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary
```

In your class:

```
Private Shared stateFileName As String = "SavedState.bin"

Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    saveState(Me)
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    loadState(Me)
End Sub
```

And these are the methods you will use to save and load states. The save state method:

```
Private Shared Sub saveState(instance As Form)
    Dim controlProperties As Dictionary(Of String, Object) =
        instance.Controls.OfType(Of Control).ToDictionary(Of String, Object)(
            Function(c) c.Name,
            Function(c)
                ' You can support different types of controls here too
                If TypeOf c Is NumericUpDown Then
                    Return CType(c, NumericUpDown).Value
                ElseIf TypeOf c Is ComboBox Then
                    Return CType(c, ComboBox).SelectedIndex
                Else
                    ' All other controls get their text property saved
                    ' .Text is a property of Control
                    Return c.Text
                End If
            End Function)
    Using myFileStream As Stream = File.Create(stateFileName)
        Dim serializer As New BinaryFormatter
        serializer.Serialize(myFileStream, controlProperties)
    End Using
End Sub
```

The load state method:

```
Private Shared Sub loadState(instance As Form)
    If File.Exists(stateFileName) Then
        Using myFileStream As Stream = File.OpenRead(stateFileName)
            Dim deserializer As New BinaryFormatter()
            Dim controlProperties = CType(deserializer.Deserialize(myFileStream), Dictionary(Of String, Object))
            For Each c As Control In instance.Controls
                If controlProperties.ContainsKey(c.Name) Then
                    ' You can support different types of controls here too
                    If TypeOf c Is NumericUpDown Then
                        CType(c, NumericUpDown).Value = CDec(controlProperties(c.Name))
                    ElseIf TypeOf c Is ComboBox Then
                        CType(c, ComboBox).SelectedIndex = CInt(controlProperties(c.Name))
                    Else
                        c.Text = controlProperties(c.Name).ToString()
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        End Using
    End If
End Sub
```

You should add exception handling, and note that a binary file is not meant to be edited by a human without the assistance of a machine.

Comment: as more details trickled out in comments, a Dictionary wont work and something else is creating the file, if that thing also re-reads updated values then it may need to stay a CSV.  Hard to tell it is all too abstract and vague.

Comment: @Plutonix Ah that wasn't very clear to me. The question makes a little more sense now. Would be nice to see an example of the required csv... Oh well, maybe someone else could use this method to serialize their form.

Comment: it would be nice to know what logical thing is represented too - a UserControl made of a CBO+NUD might work.  It is more and more an XY question

Comment: Sorry for being too vague guys.  I've added a bit more info to the OP.  This stuff is pretty new to me, hence the lack of knowing what all I need to include in the original post.